# How can I use both image and color brush in xaml rectangle

Tags: xaml

```
`<Rectangle Uid="a8" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Chess;component/Images/blackRook.bmp"></ImageBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush></SolidColorBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>`
```

SolidColorBrush is having blue underline with message "Fill property is set more than once"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the Fill property will only Fill a Single Brush at a time. See the documentation here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

A quick and relatively simple workaround would be to perhaps embed your Rectangle in a Border Control to get the effect you're after. So something like;

```
<Border Grid.Column="1">
  <Border.Background>
    <SolidorLinearGradientBrush/>
  </Border.Background>
   <Rectangle Uid="a8">
     <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Chess;component/Images/blackRook.bmp"/>
     </Rectangle.Fill>
   </Rectangle>
</Border>
```

Hope this helps, Cheers!